# Anyone know how to strip quote characters from a string in DOS batch script?

Tags: dos, cmd

Does anyone know how to strip quote characters from a string in DOS batch script?  Stripping characters is easy with the string replace function but stripping quotes (or exclamation marks) is seeming to be a little tougher.  Here is my test script I am trying to get working:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo.
set "NAME=Izomorphius"
call :append NAME " is my dear friend."
echo Message: %NAME%
echo.
goto :end
:: Functions
:append @varname @value
IF NOT "%3"=="" (
  echo Too many arguments to function.
)
set vara=%1
set stra=%2
set stra=%stra:""=%
set "%1=!%1! %2"
exit /B 0
:end
pause
```

Here is the output of this script:

```
Message: Izomorphius " is my dear friend."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` modifier will strip enclosing quotes from a paramenter. Type `HELP CALL` from the command prompt for a complete list of modifiers. The same modifiers are also available for FOR variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo.
set "NAME=Izomorphius"
call :append NAME " is my dear friend."
echo Message: %NAME%
echo.
goto :end

:: Functions

:append @varname @value
IF NOT "%~3"=="" echo Too many arguments to function.
set "%~1=!%~1! %~2"
exit /B 0

:end
pause
```

Comment: Ahh!  I  cant believe I overlooked that.  Thanks!